# Different data type array

Tags: c

I created a program to calculate the net run rate of several teams using few arrays. Everything works fine but in the end NRR shows as 0.0000000.

net run rate is a `double` array and all other arrays are `int`

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
    net_run_rate[i]=(((TRS[i]/TBF[i])*6)-((TRC[i]/TBB)*6));
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you know how integer division is happening?

Comment: Actually no. I will be happy if you can explain me.

Comment: Well, it will yield only the integer part of the result. Now check the values which you divide. Which will be `0` in case the numerator is less than the denominator.

Comment: @JayarajRohan, 10/4 will give you 2, 10/11 will give you zero.

Comment: Thank you @Eugene Sh. I got it

Comment: `net_run_rate[i]=((((double)TRS[i]/TBF[i])*6)-(((double)TRC[i]/TBB)*6));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the numerator to double first. I would add something like this:

net_run_rate[i] = (TRS[i] + 0.0 )/TBF[i];

I have tried in C# and it works.

Comment: Just `(double)TRS[i]`. Why add zero?

Comment: A better syntax would be to use an explicit type cast on one operand: ((double)TRS[i])/TBF[i]

Comment: @lurker, adding a double to an int forces an implicit type cast of the int to a double, then the result of the expression is a double.

Comment: I tried explicit conversion first but (double)TRS[i])/TBF[i] gave a zero.

Comment: @nicomp yes I'm aware of that. So does dividing or multiplying by 1.0. My point was, why bother? I'm just saying that's a bit more obscure than just typecasting, as you indicated by re-iterating my suggestion.

Comment: @Tajreenkhan did you do both of the subexpressions? You have two that need type casting. `net_run_rate[i]=((((double)TRS[i]/TBF[i])*6)-(((double)TRC[i]/TBB)*6));` And you should be doing this in C, not C#.

Comment: @lurker Impossible, it is, to know that your question was rhetorical.